# How to export multiple html tables side by side to pdf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf.js

Dears,I am getting data from c# API to angulerjs scope , and 2 javascript arrays showing days name and numbers.
i am displaying all these data on 3 small html tables inside one big html table.
I have a one big table contains 3 small tales beside each other wants to export them side by side to pdf file , any help

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<div  id="content" class="row" style="    max-height: calc(100vh - 150px); overflow:auto;     padding: 0 5px;">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover myTable master" style="font-size: 10px;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="du in duration | unique:'ID'">
                                    <td class="employeemeta">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover myTable" style="font-size: 10px;">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th rowspan="2">ID</th>
                                                    <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
                                                    <th rowspan="2">Position</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>{{du.ID}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{du.Name}}</td>
                                                    <td>{{du.Position}}</td>
                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="employeedata">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover myTable" style="font-size: 10px;">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th rowspan="3">Type</th>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <!--<th rowspan="2">Type</th>-->
                                                    <th ng-repeat="r in rangetxt">{{r.Day}}</th>

                                                    <!--<th rowspan="3"></th>-->

                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th ng-repeat="dt in dateArray">{{dt.Day}}</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr ng-repeat="df in duration | filter : du.StaffKey | limitTo:3 ">


                                                    <td>{{df.TypeTransDesc}}</td>
                                                    <!--<td ng-repeat="d in dateArray">
                                                        <span ng-repeat="dxc in duration">

                                                            <span ng-repeat="hg in dxc" ng-if="hg==d.Day">
                                                                {{dxc[d.Day]}}
                                                            </span>
                                                        </span>

                                                    <td>-->
                                                    <td ng-repeat="x in dateArray ">

                                                        <span ng-repeat="(key,value) in df" ng-if="key=='D'+x.Day">
                                                            {{value}}

                                                        </span>
                                                    </td>

                                                </tr>

                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>

                                    <td class="employeesum">
                                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover myTable">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>WD</th>
                                                    <th>VAC</th>
                                                    <th>PER</th>
                                                    <th>off</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>100</td>
                                                    <td>200</td>
                                                    <td>300</td>
                                                    <td>400</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

javascript

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });
        doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    });
```

Comment: could you please tell did my answer worked or not?

Comment: thank you very much for replying and sorry for being late , it successfully export pdf file, but only the third table has data , the other tables donnot include data, any help, thanks in advance  ...... I am calling the js code in button click.???

Comment: when i removed the rowspan from the first table it shows some data

Comment: what jspdf version you are using? I think it's better to use jspdf 1.5.x version

Comment: i downloaded jspdf 1.5.3 but still one table only shows data, would you like to take teamviewer, thanks in adavance

Comment: is it simple to export it Excel ?

Comment: could you please codepen or stackblitz of that ? or atleast provide component ts and html file? I will try to reproduce in mine.